# What is nmake equivalent of 'configure --prefix=DIR && make all install '?

Tags: c++, nmake

I would like my nmake output to go to a particular directory.

Comment: Do you realize that `configure` does (typically) a lot more than setting the "output directory"?

Comment: Yes, I have a corresponding Makefile.msc.

Comment: I hate it when I find a question that looks like just what I am looking for... and it turns out to be my own from 3 months ago.  Doh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short bit is that there isn't such a thing as Make and configure do two [different things](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/27.html). The configure is what creates a Makefile, and a Makefile is what actually contains the compiler commands to build the software. Together they create what is called a build system. To specify the target directory, you'll need to review what creates that makefile for you. However, if you do not generate a Makefile, it is likely that there is a variable which you can override with your target directory, something like:`nmake DESTDIR="Path"`

With your added comment regarding your file, if it's set-up like [this project](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/support/png2pdf/makefile.msc), then you'll can use `nmake PREFIX="Path"`